# Abort Boost Graph DFS on Back Edge

Tags: c++, boost, graph, depth-first-search

I am trying to improve performance for in my Graph algorithm and I am encountering some problems.

My graph typedef looks like this: ¨

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::multisetS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, indexProperty> graph_t;
typedef boost::graph_traits<graph_t>::vertex_descriptor vertex_descriptor_t;
typedef boost::graph_traits<graph_t>::edge_descriptor edge_descriptor_t;
```

The graph I am working on is quite big, it has around 5.8 million edges and 100 vertices.

What I am doing is the following:

1. Determine strongly connected components of the graph
2. Perform Depth First Search on each component in order to detect cycles in the graph.

I look for cycles in the graph by searching for back edges within the graph.
For each cycle I detect, I have to perform an operation that changes the graph. (I have to remove the cycle edges from the graph). 
After removal of the cycle I restart the DFS to find the next cycle.

My question now is:

**How can I terminate the DFS on back edge detection?**

I did some research and found the following question:
[following question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711549/stop-boostdepth-first-search-along-a-particular-depth-if-certain-criteria-is-m)

There it is proposed to use Boosts depth first visit. However, in the 
[documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/depth_first_visit.html) It says that the terminator function is called immediately after the call to discover_vertex. Is it possible to terminate after a call to back_edge?

Also, is it possible to use depth_first_visit directly, without copying the boost source code as proposed by the aforementioned question?

What I am doing until now is storing a flag in the visitor that is set to true as soon as a cycle is detected and checking this flag on every function call in the visitor. This adds a lot of unnecessary function calls to the dfs and takes forever.

Thanks for your help!

**To clarify:**
The algorithm I am using is described on geeksforgeeks dot org/detect-cycle-in-a-graph (sorry, I can't post more than two links)

What I am doing in pseudocode is:

```
 For each strongly connected component in g
   do
      perform dfs until first back edge
      perform some task on the cycle edges
      remove cycle edges from g
   until no cycle in DFS
```

@petr: Why do you think a restart of dfs is not needed?

Comment: Could you clarify your actual problem? What do you mean by "detect cycles"? Because for strongly connected components and DFS there you do not need to restart DFS.

Comment: added more onformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical solution for terminating boost::depth_first_search is to throw an exception (of a type you define yourself). Your code can then catch an exception, do whatever you want, and continue.

That said, I agree with concerns about restarting DFS on each back edge. If you have a strongly connected component, you can just remove all in edges of its root vertex, and find SCCs in the resulting graph? But anyway, that's a topic for algorithms.stackexchange.com, if you want to abort DFS, exception is the solution.

Comment: See also: [BGL FAQ: How do I perform an early exit from an algorithm such as BFS?](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/doc/faq.html)